# Cant start linux "screen" with logging to specific output file

Tags: gnu-screen

I have the problem that I want to enable logging of a screen session at the start of it which then saves the log to a specific file.
What I have until now was:

```
screen -AmdSL cod2war /home/cod2server/scripts/service_28969.sh
```

while `service_28969.sh` is a shell script that will call other scripts which produce output.
I started multiple of those screen-sessions with different names, for example

```
screen -AmdSL cod2sd /home/cod2server/scripts/service_28962.sh
```

`-L` enables logging as the [screen's man](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) say, and will safe the ouput in a file called 'screenlog.0', now since I have multiple of those screens only one of it produces output saved in that log file (I can't find other 'screenlog.*' files in that folder).

I thought to use the `-Logfile "file"` option from the same man page, but it doesn't work for me and I can't find out what I'm doing wrong..

```
screen -Logfile cod2sd.log -AmdS cod2sd /home/u268450/cod2server/scripts/service_28962.sh
```

will produce the following error:

```
Use: screen [-opts] [cmd [args]]
 or: screen -r [host.tty]

Options:
[...]
Error: Unknown option Logfile
```

and

```
screen -AmdS cod2sd /home/u268450/cod2server/scripts/service_28962.sh -Logfile cod2sd.log
```

will run without any error and start the screen but without the logging at all..

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but I need to launch a lot of named screen, ideally each with a different logfile, so I cannot use .screenrc, have you had any luck in fixing this?

Comment: unfortunately: no

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a logfile from within the default startup `~/.screenrc` file using a line like

```
logfile mylog.log
```

To do this from the command line you can create a file `mystartup` to hold the above line, then use option `-c mystartup` to tell screen to read this file for setup instead of the default. If you also need to have `~/.screenrc` read, you can add the `source` command to your startup file.  The final result would look something like:

```
echo 'logfile mylog.log
source ~/.screenrc' >mystartup
screen -AmdSL cod2war -c mystartup /home/cod2server/scripts/service_28969.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this error myself and found this solution that worked with my python file, wanted to share for anyone else who might run into this issue:

```bash
screen -L -Logfile LOGFILENAME.LOG -dmS SCREENNAME python3 ./FILENAME.PY
```

I have no idea if this is the 'correct' way but it works.

`-L` enables logging

`-Logfile LOGFILENAME.LOG` declares what to call the log file and file format

`-dmS SCREENNAME`, `dm` runs in detached mode and `S` allows you to name the session

`python3 ./FILENAME.PY` in this case is my script but I assume that any other script here functions

I have tried a different ordering of these commands and this was the only way I managed to have them all run without issues. Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
screen -L -Logfile /Logs/Screen/`date +%Y%m%d`_screen.log
```

The configs I checked:

```
screen version 4.08.00 (GNU) 05-Feb-20 on FreeBSD 12.2
and 
version 4.06.02 (GNU) 23-Oct-17 on Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
and
version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06 on  Mac OS X 10.9.5.
```